# Launching on Amazon Beanstalk: "Could not launch environment: 2 validation errors detected:"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to launch an app to Elastic Beanstalk on Amazon, I have provided an S3 bucket url as the location for the source code. But here is the error I'm getting:

```
Could not launch environment: 2 validation errors detected: Value '' at 'versionLabel' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [^/]+; Value '' at 'versionLabel' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The versionLabel is parsed from the s3Key.  The S3Key is generated from your s3bucket path. The error is caused by incorrect parsing logic.  If your artifact is nested in multiple levels within a s3 bucket, the parsing logic for the s3Key includes a forward slash.  Amazon is fixing this problem.  You can create a new version and specify the s3Key via the following command (using aws cli):

aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name test-application --version-label 20141005-01 --source-bundle 'S3Bucket=yourBucket,S3Key=web-application/war/1.0.0/test.war'

I believe you can still use s3 if you don't nest the artifact.

Comment: Just to show how much AWS actually cares... after almost 6 years the problem is still there.